# setting an input mask for an IP address in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am writing an application which involves users entering in IP addresses in the following format: "198.109.234.250"

I am using an ajax control at the minute that creates the mask like this:
 _ _ *.* _ *.* _ *.* _ _ which is fine because it will not allow letters to be entered just numbers.

Here is my question:

How do i set the maximum value for each three digit section of the I.P? like so that the maximum for each section can only be 250? like this: 250.250.250.250

I have been looking for an attribute within the ajax extender but cant seem to find one.

Comment: Which control are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a regular expression expert, but you can use RegularExpressionValidator for validating IP Address.

For example,

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="IPAddressTextBox" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
    runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
    ControlToValidate="IPAddressTextBox" 
    Text="IP Address must in format - 255.255.255.255"
    Display="Dynamic" />
```